# Jupyte Notebook in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run the command 'jupyter  notebook' on WSL terminal.

It gives me the following message.

```
jupyter notebook
[I 21:03:59.311 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/subbu
[I 21:03:59.312 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 21:03:59.313 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=1969d6d50e8d3450bb8523fd2b30d8e1d3afc792c730223a
[I 21:03:59.313 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 21:03:59.323 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 21:03:59.323 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/subbu/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-49-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=1969d6d50e8d3450bb8523fd2b30d8e1d3afc792c730223a
```

When paste the the link in a browse (nboth mozilla an chrome), it says 'unable to connect, and the notebook does not launch.

Can you please help me in sorting this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if any firewall is blocking any connections? Are you using WSL1 or WSL2 (insider builds)? Does other program like ssh work?

Comment: Which link did you use?